# Verificar se tabela existe antes de inserir valor no banco de dados SqfLite -- Flutter

Tags: sql, mobile, datatable, flutter

Estou desenvolvendo um app, meu problema é que com atualizações do aplicativo eu posso usar outras tabelas que ainda não existem no banco de dados existente. A solução que me veio a cabeça foi sempre antes de inserir um valor verificar se a tabela ja exite, mas estou tendo probles para fazer isso.

## Query:

```
await db.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Order (
                id INT PRIMARY KEY,
                order TEXT NOT NULL
              )
      ''');
```

## Erro Recebido:

```
Exception has occurred.
SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(near "Order": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Order (
                id INT PRIMARY KEY,
                order TEXT NOT NULL
              )) sql '    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Order (
                id INT PRIMARY KEY,
                order TEXT NOT NULL
              )
      ' args []})
```

A query tem erros de syntax ou o SqfLite não suporta esse tipo de abordagem?
O que eu poderia fazer nesse casa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema está relacionado a palavra `ORDER`.

`ORDER` é uma palavra reservada do banco de dados, o que você pode fazer é modificar o nome da sua tabela e campo...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Orders (id INT PRIMARY KEY, orders TEXT NOT NULL);
```

Pode fazer o teste aqui [nesse site](https://sqliteonline.com/) se quiser, pra ver como funciona.

*Link útil: [SQLite Order By](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-order-by/)*